# How to declare a sequence in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, sequence

I need to declare a fixed sequence of numbers. How do I do this?

For example, is it (I'm guessing here):

```
<xsl:element name="xsl:param">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">MySequence</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:sequence>(1,2,3,4)</xsl:sequence>
</xsl:element>
```

or

```
<xsl:element name="xsl:param">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">MySequence</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:sequence>1,2,3,4</xsl:sequence>
</xsl:element>
```

or what?

Thanks

Comment: This is a little confusing. Why are you creating an element named `xsl:param`? Are you generating a stylesheet from a stylesheet?

Comment: It's a long story, but basically this will be used with Schematron (which I was hoping not to go into). Do you know the answer to the question? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using XSLT 2.0, you can just create the sequence directly in the `select` like:

```
<xsl:param name="MySequence" select="('1','2','3','4')"/>
```

XSLT based verification...

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="seq" select="('23453','74365','98','653')"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="$seq">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('Item ',position(),': ',.,'&#xA;')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to any XML input produces:

```
Item 1: 23453
Item 2: 74365
Item 3: 98
Item 4: 653
```

Comment: That looks good. Just checking - will that declare a sequence rather than just a string containing a comma separated list?

Comment: @bukko - Yes. Please see my update for an example verification.

Comment: @bukko - Updated again to include an example of "random" numbers mentioned in the comment on Ian Roberts' answer.

Comment: Top answer! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @bukko - You're welcome. Also note that you can omit the quotes around the numbers if you like. That will keep it a sequence of numbers instead of a sequence of strings.

Comment: Yup sorry I typed that comment before I saw you last one (I deleted it some time ago :] )

Answer (score 1):

To build a sequence in the XSLT 2.0 sense you use a `select` e.g.

```
<xsl:sequence select="1 to 4" />
```

But if you're adding the value to an element you may prefer `value-of`

```
<xsl:value-of select="1 to 4" separator="," />
```

Given the snippet in the question, this would generate output XML of

```
<xsl:param name="MySequence">1,2,3,4</xsl:param>
```

Which makes the value of the generated param a comma separated string. If you actually want the `param` value to be a sequence in the generated XSLT then you need to generate a `select` attribute instead of using element content

```
<xsl:element name="xsl:param">
  <xsl:attribute name="name" select="'MySequence'"/>
  <xsl:attribute name="select">
    <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="1 to 4" separator=","/>
    <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

Giving output of

```
<xsl:param name="MySequence" select="(1,2,3,4)" />
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do this for a random set of numbers? e.g. 23453,74365,98,653

Comment: @bukko I've added some more detail. If you're not actually making use of the sequence constructors then you could just put the value in by hand: `<xsl:attribute name="select" select="'(23453,74365,98,653)'"/>`